# In IIS, how do I set environment variables for specific CGI scripts

Tags: windows, iis

I have two cgi scripts from a product I can't alter.  One needs a specific Environment Variable to be set.  The other should be left alone.

Is there a way, in IIS, to do the same thing as apache's `SetEnv` command just for one of the CGI scripts?

Ciao!

Comment: bueller? bueller? bueller? ....

Comment: This may help (if you are still interested!).
<http://serverfault.com/questions/672726/in-iis7-is-it-possible-to-have-custom-environment-variables-per-web-site>

Comment: You should post a link and summary as an answer and I'll accept your version instead.  Using different users, with different variables, never occurred to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use two different application pool, run them under different user accounts and set user-based environment variables
See full answer here https://serverfault.com/questions/672726/in-iis7-is-it-possible-to-have-custom-environment-variables-per-web-site%3E

Answer (score 1):

It's been a year, and still haven't found a way to do this.  It's hard to prove a negative, but I think this is as I'm getting in practice.

The workarounds for this include registry keys and system-wide variables. *sigh*